# Access artifacts from multiple builds of a project through a URL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a parameterized Jenkins project that takes in a couple of parameters say client and environment. When I run the build, I specify the client and environment. I want to be able to create a folder for the "stack" which stores the artifacts from the build (either through a shell script or ArtifactDeployer plugin). So, after a number of builds, I'll see something like

```
job
  archives
    client1-ppd
      file1, file2, file3 ...
    client1-prod
      file1, file2, file3 ...
    client2-uat
      file1, file2, file3 ...
```

I would like to be able to access these artifacts through the Jenkins URL.  Currently on the Project, I have the "Workspace", "Last Successful Artifacts" and "Recent changes" links.  Can I create another link for the "archives" folder which would be a directory listing. So, then I could walk through the tree to get to a build?

The Artifacts Deployer plugin only has the Last Successful Artifacts and even here, the links are ".../artifact.1", ".../artifact.2" etc.  Which is not very useful for what I want since I want the names of the file - file1, file2 etc.

Is there some way to achieve what I want?  Some way to customize the links in a project?